# Cross Platform Flash Player Embedding

Tags: c++, flash, cross-platform

I need to embed the Flash player in a native application (C++) in a cross platform way (at least Windows and Mac OSX). I need to allow the Flash gui to make calls back to the native application to do things that Flash normally can’t do (e.g. write to the file system, talk to devices, loading native image processing libraries, etc). The Adobe AIR runtime is too restrictive so it is unfortunately not an option. I’ve used ActiveX hosting in Windows previously, but is there a cross platform gui toolkit that solves this problem for both Windows and OSX? If not what are my options for embedding Flash on OSX?

EDIT: Must support Actionscript 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is [MDM Zinc](http://multidmedia.com). Win and OSX aren't 100% equal, and you should make sure it will do everything you need, but it may work for you.

Comment: I've used zinc in a bunch of projects and I quite like it. I've never done anything especially advanced though so i'm not sure if it'll keep up then.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, but [Scaleform GFx](https://www.scaleform.com/products/gfx) does exactly what you want -- it's cross-platform, and can make calls back and forth between native code and Flash.  It also supports a number of different rendering engines (DirectX, OpenGL, etc.).

Comment: I need a solution that supports Actionscript 3.0. Unfortunately Scaleform is as 2.0 only.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [SWHX](http://haxe.org/com/libs/swhx) and if you want a higher level API and a GUI, [HippoHX](http://www.hippohx.com/).

HTH