# Custom standalone executable that allows to run Flash content from desktop

Tags: flash

I want to create a custom executable which is similar to the [Flash Projector to play swf](http://animation.about.com/od/faqs/f/faq_projector.htm) content. The use case for this is the following: I have Ui components on the swf which exchange messages with my c++ cli executable for sending and receiving events. 
Is there any example to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is answered by the following questions:

- [Embedding Flash Player in a C++ or Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214411/embedding-flash-player-in-a-c-or-java-application)
- [Cross Platform Flash Player Embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060679/cross-platform-flash-player-embedding)

Also found some related articles using the flash ocx/activex [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/flashcontrol.aspx).